# I can only select one object at a time where as before i could select muliple

Tags: modeling, objects, edit-mode, selection-tools, object-mode

I have 5 different objects in my collection currently. Before this setting triggered. I could select any part or any object (multiple or one at a time) then edit the number of selections I made using the shift key. Now, I can only select one object then edit that single object.

I want to edit 4 of 5 objects currently at the same time via selecting the faces on each object but I am suddenly only allowed to edit one face of one object at a time.

What setting controls the ability to select objects?

I'm quite new and losing my ability to edit multiple objects at once is quite frustrating.

Thank you to who ever answers.

Comment: maybe your shift key isn't working my friend , try to use box select by hitting B on your keyboard

Comment: Shift-select all your objects in Object mode then tab into Edit mode and you'll be able to edit all of them.

Comment: I did figure out the problem for any one new to blender! You have to select all of the objects you will be editing in the objects tab prior to switching to edit. If you just switch to edit you can only work on one item at a time. If you pull all the objects into edit then it will work. Same as what John Eason said!

Comment: You can also Shift or box select them all in the 3D view before going inot Edit mode. Whichever is more convenient.